# convert scientific notation in string format to numeric in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, spark-shell

```
Day_Date,timeofday_desc,Timeofday_hour,Timeofday_minute,Timeofday_second,value
2017-12-18,12:21:02 AM,0,21,2,“1.779209040E+08”
2017-12-19,12:21:02 AM,0,21,2,“1.779209040E+08”
2017-12-20,12:30:52 AM,0,30,52,“1.779209040E+08”
2017-12-21,12:30:52 AM,0,30,52,“1.779209040E+08”
2017-12-22,12:47:10 AM,0,47,10,“1.779209040E+08”
2017-12-23,12:47:10 AM,0,47,10,“1.779209040E+08”
2017-12-24,02:46:59 AM,2,46,59,“1.779209040E+08”
2017-12-25,02:46:59 AM,2,46,59,“1.779209040E+08”
2017-12-26,03:10:27 AM,3,10,27,“1.779209040E+08”
2017-12-27,03:10:27 AM,3,10,27,“1.779209040E+08”
2017-12-28,03:52:08 AM,3,52,8,“1.779209040E+08”
```

I am trying to convert `value` column to `177920904`

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("s", 'value.cast("Decimal(10,4)")).drop("value").withColumnRenamed("s", "value")
```

also tried casting value as `Float`, `Double`. Always get null as output

```
df1.select("value").show()


+-----------+
|   value   |
+-----------+
|       null|
|       null|
|       null|
|       null|
|       null|
|       null|
|       null|
|       null|
```

---

```
df.printSchema

root
 |-- Day_Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timeofday_desc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Timeofday_hour: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Timeofday_minute: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Timeofday_second: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just need to cast it to decimal with enough room to fit the number.

Decimal is Decimal(precision, scale), so Decimal(10, 4) means 10 digits in total, 6 at the left of the dot, and 4 to the right, so the number does not fit in your Decimal type.

From the documentation

> precision represents the total number of digits that can be
> represented
>
> scale represents the number of fractional digits. This value must be
> less than or equal to precision. A scale of 0 produces integral
> values, with no fractional part

Since you don't want any number to the right, you can try this

```
df.withColumn("s", 'value.cast("Decimal(10,0)"))
```

If you want to keep 4 decimal digits, you can just change it to

```
df.withColumn("s", 'value.cast("Decimal(14,4)"))
```

**INPUT**

```
df.show
+---------------+
|          value|
+---------------+
|1.779209040E+08|
+---------------+
```

**OUTPUT**

```
scala> df.withColumn("s", 'value.cast("Decimal(10,0)")).show
+---------------+---------+
|          value|        s|
+---------------+---------+
|1.779209040E+08|177920904|
+---------------+---------+
```

**FULL SOLUTION**

Without dropping nor renamig

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("value", 'value.cast("Decimal(10,0)"))
```

**FIX INPUT DATA**

As I said in the comment, the problem is that your numbers contain some weird characters around them, you should remove it before casting

ORIGINAL

```
scala> df.show
+----------+--------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+
|  Day_Date|timeofday_desc|Timeofday_hour|Timeofday_minute|Timeofday_second|            value|
+----------+--------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+
|2017-12-18|   12:21:02 AM|             0|              21|               2| ?1.779209040E+08|
|2017-12-19|   12:21:02 AM|             0|              21|               2|?1.779209040E+08?|
|2017-12-20|   12:30:52 AM|             0|              30|              52| ?1.779209040E+08|
|2017-12-21|   12:30:52 AM|             0|              30|              52| ?1.779209040E+08|
|2017-12-22|   12:47:10 AM|             0|              47|              10| ?1.779209040E+08|
|2017-12-23|   12:47:10 AM|             0|              47|              10| ?1.779209040E+08|
|2017-12-24|   02:46:59 AM|             2|              46|              59| ?1.779209040E+08|
|2017-12-25|   02:46:59 AM|             2|              46|              59| ?1.779209040E+08|
|2017-12-26|   03:10:27 AM|             3|              10|              27| ?1.779209040E+08|
|2017-12-27|   03:10:27 AM|             3|              10|              27| ?1.779209040E+08|
|2017-12-28|   03:52:08 AM|             3|              52|               8| ?1.779209040E+08|
+----------+--------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

There are many ways to remove them, a quick one is with an UDF and a regular expression to remove everything but numbers, letters, dot, + and -

```
 def clean(input: String) = input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.-]", "")
 val cleanUDF = udf(clean _ )
df.withColumn("value", cleanUDF($"value").cast(DecimalType(10,0))).show
+----------+--------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+---------+
|  Day_Date|timeofday_desc|Timeofday_hour|Timeofday_minute|Timeofday_second|    value|
+----------+--------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+---------+
|2017-12-18|   12:21:02 AM|             0|              21|               2|177920904|
|2017-12-19|   12:21:02 AM|             0|              21|               2|177920904|
|2017-12-20|   12:30:52 AM|             0|              30|              52|177920904|
|2017-12-21|   12:30:52 AM|             0|              30|              52|177920904|
|2017-12-22|   12:47:10 AM|             0|              47|              10|177920904|
|2017-12-23|   12:47:10 AM|             0|              47|              10|177920904|
|2017-12-24|   02:46:59 AM|             2|              46|              59|177920904|
|2017-12-25|   02:46:59 AM|             2|              46|              59|177920904|
|2017-12-26|   03:10:27 AM|             3|              10|              27|177920904|
|2017-12-27|   03:10:27 AM|             3|              10|              27|177920904|
|2017-12-28|   03:52:08 AM|             3|              52|               8|177920904|
+----------+--------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+---------+
```

Comment: don't know why but i am still getting null

Comment: With the code i posted? Post it yours again please, just to check if there are some minor errors or typos. Which is the data type of the numbers in the original dataframe? Strings or what?

Comment: used same code `df.withColumn("s", 'value.cast("Decimal(10,0)")).show`, and my column s is still none. can you please post how do you read the csv?

Comment: I created one from scratch in the shell. Please print a df.show and a df.printSchema

Comment: I think the problem may be with those weirs quotation marks around the number

Comment: if you print df.show you'll see some weird characters around your number, those are the ones which cause the problem when casting

Comment: ok i got the problem, its because of `“1.779209040E+08”` double quotes because of the excel it got different type of double quotes. with normal double quotes or by replacing these double quotes you can easily cast it with decimal.