# Hive data type for large values

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am learning hive and spark

Which data type should be use to store value like 1.00E+07 ,-1.00E+08

I have tried bigint but it is storing as null.

Comment: Are your values coming in exactly in scientific notation format? Bigint is the data type you want, but if your values come in like this: `1.00E+07` then you first need to convert them. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55914742/convert-scientific-notation-in-string-format-to-numeric-in-spark-dataframe

Comment: @wtfzambo yes some values are coming as 1.00E+07,-1.00E+07 other are coming as -330000,25000 like that , is there a way to store the value as is ? or hive to convert it automatically

Comment: admittedly I never had to face a situation  in which values in the same column come in different formats. The scientific notation can be casted to decimal by following the other question I linked. I would try following the suggestions in the linked thread and see if it applies  to both situations. Otherwise you would need to address each case independently,  probably with a UDF.